# How HTTP redirects(302) works during an ajax call

Tags: ajax, http, redirect

I was asked to implement a "one session per account" limitation on an old java 7/struts 1 web application.

During development, I'm getting a behavior which I can't really understand.

So if there's an account "Account-A" currently logged in with a session "Session-1234" and then the same account gets logged in but with a different session "Session-4567" then the session "Session-1234" is marked to be invalidated in the next request performed by that session.

During the process of invalidation of the "Session-1234", one of the steps is redirecting(302) the client to the login page.

Now is what I don't understand.

If the request is coming in "synchronous" mode, everything works as expected.

User clicks some link

1. Server  -> invalidates session and redirects(302) login.
2. Browser -> detects 302 looks for Location header and performs a get.
3. Server  -> serves the resource.
4. Browser -> show login and update the URL.

If the request is coming in "asynchronous" mode aka AJAX, now I have problems because what happens is that the page never changes and the content of the login is displayed right there.

My question is not how to solve this "problem", but rather have a really good grasp on why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a programmatic client, you have 2 main options:

1. Don't use cookies, use the `Authorization` header and let the server emit a `401`, telling the client their token is now invalid.
2. With your javascript client, read if the server returned a `302` response and `Location` header and respond to that.

#2 is basically a hack that lets you mimic the standard browsers' behavior. #1 is more appropriate for an API.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I'm really looking for an understanding of the inner workings of the process of a server redirecting(302) a client when the client request was made by ajax. As I said in case the request is made by ajax and then the server redirects, then what happens is that the page(URL) doesn't change and the content of the redirect is displayed on the same page. A great confusion!!!